# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.graph_objects'

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Trying to use `'plotly.graph_objects'` but I get this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.graph_objects'

How do I download module and apply using anaconda navigator

Comment: `import plotly.graph_objs as go`

Comment: which is the one? I used graph_objects in google colab without problem. should we use graph_objs in a local machine?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use instead:

`from plotly import graph_objs as go`

Comment: As of version 4 we've also aliased `plotly.graph_objects` so you can do also `import plotly.graph_objects as go`

Comment: version 4 of what?

Answer (score 2):

This is the approach now mostly used in the plotly docs. [Example](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

Comment: yes and it does not work. that is why this question

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was because i was using python 2.7 instead of python 3